# Dynamics CRM: how to make workflows to work for every user

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, share

I've some workflows in CRM but they work for the owner, also tried to use sharing them between users but with no result.

How to configure workflows to work for everyone (every organization, user team etc.) by default?

Sultan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the workflow editing screen, there's a field called Scope where you can set it to either User or Organization. Setting it to Organization will make the workflow run for every user regardless of their business unit, team, etc.